# What is the simplest way to enable TLS 1.2 for soap web proxy?

Tags: .net, ssl

I have a large legacy solution which is extensively using an auto generated soap web proxy. I want to configure it to support TLS 1.2 connections only, so i need to set

> System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
>   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

What is the simplest way to achieve this? Sub-classing of the proxy does not work for me, because it require a massive code change. And using a partial class does not provide me with good point to attach the configuration code.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I've posted my solution. I hope it will give you some clue for yours.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've chosen is to call the initialization for every context i need to. It could exists a better solution, so i'm open to improve mine.

First i define:

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    private static readonly object ensureInitializationField = null;

    static Bootstrapper()
    {
        // REFERENCE: enable TLS 1.2
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
            SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes the code in the static constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Code in the static constructor is called only once.
    /// </remarks>
    public static void EnsureInitialization()
    {
        Equals(ensureInitializationField, null);
    }
}
```

And later i call it from the desired context (e.g. Global.asax.cs) like this:

```
Bootstrapper.EnsureInitialization();
```